# SQL Reduce table by merging rows based on identical "key" columns, merging non-identical "non-key" columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table which contains lots of redundant information, that I would like to reduce. Starting with the example, I would like to move from this table:

```
+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
|  facility   | device | location | property |       name       | data_type | rate |
+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
| Chicago     | SVR2   |    501.1 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10 |
| Chicago     | SVR3   |    501.1 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10 |
| ...         |        |          |          |                  |           |      |
| Chicago     | SVR64  |    501.1 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10 |
| Chicago     | SVR1   |    501.1 | OS       | Operating System | int       |    0 |
| Minneapolis | SVR1   |       65 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10 |
+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
```

to this table

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
| facility | device | location | property |       name       | data_type | rate |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
| .*       | SVR\d+ | .*       | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10 |
| Chicago  | SVR\d+ | .*       | OS       | Operating System | int       |    0 |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-----------+------+
```

most likely via this intermediate table:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+------+
|      facility       |       device        | location | property |     name      | data_type | rate |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+------+
| Chicago,Minneapolis | SVR2,SVR3,...,SVR64 | 501.1,65 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power | float     |   10 |
| Minneapolis         | SVR1                |       65 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power | float     |   10 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+------+
```

So, here i consider the first 3 columns `facility`, `device`, `location` "non-key" columns and all others "key" colu,ms. I want to merge rows that have identical key column values and produce a regex expression that matches all existent non-key columns for the rows that were merged. I understand that the last is not so easy, so I'd like to get a joint set of all values occuring for the non-key columns for identical key columns.

I'd like to do this in SQLite. I have a basic idea how to get columns that have identical key columns, but I don't know how to get the joint values for the non-key columns. If it can't be done, I'll write a python script to do it.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT facility) facility, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT device) device, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT location) location, 
       property, name, data_type, rate
FROM tablename
GROUP BY property, name, data_type, rate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=eb7ffee8962d0bb53de4b1ef6bb297db).

```
> facility            | device               | location   | property | name             | data_type | rate
> :------------------ | :------------------- | :--------- | :------- | :--------------- | :-------- | ---:
> Chicago,Minneapolis | SVR2,SVR3,SVR64,SVR1 | 501.1,65.0 | MAX_POW  | Maximum Power    | float     |   10
> Chicago             | SVR1                 | 501.1      | OS       | Operating System | int       |    0
```